# Shell script templates

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, standards, ksh

What would be your suggestions for a good bash/ksh script template to use as a standard for all newly created scripts?

I usually start (after the `#!` line) with a commented-out header with a filename, synopsis, usage, return values, author(s), changelog and would fit into 80-char lines.

All documentation lines I start with double-hash symbols `##` so I can grep for them easily and local var names are prepended with "__".

Any other best practices? Tips? Naming conventions? What about return codes?

Comments on version control : we use SVN all right, but another dept in the enterprise has a separate repo and this is their script. How do I know who to contact with Q's if there is no @author info? Using entries similar to javadocs has some merit even in the shell context, IMHO, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Author(s)? Changelog?

Get a version control system!

Comment: I'm not convinced that using a `__` prefix for local variable names is beneficial.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'd extend Norman's answer to 6 lines, and the last of those is blank:

```
#!/bin/ksh
#
# @(#)$Id$
#
# Purpose
```

The third line is a version control identification string - it is actually a hybrid with an SCCS marker '`@(#)`' that can be identified by the (SCCS) program `what` and an RCS version string which is expanded when the file is put under RCS, the default VCS I use for my private use.   The RCS program `ident` picks up the expanded form of `$Id$`, which might look like `$Id: mkscript.sh,v 2.3 2005/05/20 21:06:35 jleffler Exp $`.  The fifth line reminds me that the script should have a description of its purpose at the top; I replace the word with an actual description of the script (which is why there's no colon after it, for example).

After that, there is essentially nothing standard for a shell script.  There are standard fragments that appear, but no standard fragment that appears in every script.  (My discussion assumes that scripts are written in Bourne, Korn, or POSIX (Bash) shell notations.  There's a whole separate discussion on why anyone putting a C Shell derivative after the `#!` sigil is living in sin.)

For example, this code appears in some shape or form whenever a script creates intermediate (temporary) files:

```
tmp=${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/prog.$$
trap "rm -f $tmp.?; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15

...real work that creates temp files $tmp.1, $tmp.2, ...

rm -f $tmp.?
trap 0
exit 0
```

The first line chooses a temporary directory, defaulting to /tmp if the user did not specify an alternative ($TMPDIR is very widely recognized and is standardized by POSIX).  It then creates a file name prefix including the process ID.  This is not a security measure; it is a simple concurrency measure, preventing multiple instances of the script from trampling on each other's data.  (For security, use non-predictable file names in a non-public directory.)  The second line ensures that the '`rm`' and '`exit`' commands are executed if the shell receives any of the signals SIGHUP (1), SIGINT (2), SIGQUIT (3), SIGPIPE (13) or SIGTERM (15).  The '`rm`' command removes any intermediate files that match the template; the `exit` command ensures that the status is non-zero, indicating some sort of error.  The '`trap`' of 0 means that the code is also executed if the shell exits for any reason - it covers carelessness in the section marked 'real work'.  The code at the end then removes any surviving temporary files, *before* lifting the trap on exit, and finally exits with a zero (success) status.  Clearly, if you want to exit with another status, you may - just make sure you set it in a variable before running the `rm` and `trap` lines, and then use `exit $exitval`.

I usually use the following to remove the path and suffix from the script, so I can use `$arg0` when reporting errors:

```
arg0=$(basename $0 .sh)
```

I often use a shell function to report errors:

```
error()
{
    echo "$arg0: $*" 1>&2
    exit 1
}
```

If there's only one or maybe two error exits, I don't bother with the function; if there are any more, I do because it simplifies the coding.  I also create more or less elaborate functions called `usage` to give the summary of how to use the command - again, only if there's more than one place where it would be used.

Another fairly standard fragment is an option parsing loop, using the [`getopts`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) shell built-in:

```
vflag=0
out=
file=
Dflag=
while getopts hvVf:o:D: flag
do
    case "$flag" in
    (h) help; exit 0;;
    (V) echo "$arg0: version $Revision$ ($Date$)"; exit 0;;
    (v) vflag=1;;
    (f) file="$OPTARG";;
    (o) out="$OPTARG";;
    (D) Dflag="$Dflag $OPTARG";;
    (*) usage;;
    esac
done
shift $(expr $OPTIND - 1)
```

or:

```
shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
```

The quotes around "$OPTARG" handle spaces in arguments.  The Dflag is cumulative, but the notation used here loses track of spaces in arguments.  There are (non-standard) ways to work around that problem, too.

The first shift notation works with any shell (or would do if I used back-ticks instead of '`$(...)`'.  The second works in modern shells; there might even be an alternative with square brackets instead of parentheses, but this works so I've not bothered to work out what that is.

One final trick for now is that I often have both the GNU and a non-GNU version of programs around, and I want to be able to choose which I use.  Many of my scripts, therefore, use variables such as:

```
: ${PERL:=perl}
: ${SED:=sed}
```

And then, when I need to invoke Perl or `sed`, the script uses `$PERL` or `$SED`.  This helps me when something behaves differently - I can choose the operational version - or while developing the script (I can add extra debug-only options to the command without modifying the script).  (See [Shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) for information on the `${VAR:=value}` and related notations.)

Comment: Hi @Jonathan what is the notation " : ${VAR:=file} " ? Thanks in advance

Comment: @tmow: The notation `${VAR:=file}` means that if `$VAR` is set to a non-empty value, then use that value, but if `$VAR` is not set or is set to the empty string, then use the value `file`, and set `$VAR` to that value.  So, it's a bit like (but a lot shorter than): `[ -z "$VAR" ] && VAR=file; echo $VAR`.

Answer (score 17):

I use the first set of ## lines for the usage documentation.  I can't remember now where I first saw this.

```
#!/bin/sh
## Usage: myscript [options] ARG1
##
## Options:
##   -h, --help    Display this message.
##   -n            Dry-run; only show what would be done.
##

usage() {
  [ "$*" ] && echo "$0: $*"
  sed -n '/^##/,/^$/s/^## \{0,1\}//p' "$0"
  exit 2
} 2>/dev/null

main() {
  while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    case $1 in
    (-n) DRY_RUN=1;;
    (-h|--help) usage 2>&1;;
    (--) shift; break;;
    (-*) usage "$1: unknown option";;
    (*) break;;
    esac
  done
  : do stuff.
}
```

Comment: The usage() function grepping the script looks cool at first but it fails if the script executes a `cd` anywhere and `$0` is not an absolute filename. I'd opt for the usage() function to actually echo/printf/cat the usage message.

Comment: You could determine the absolute pathname of the script and store that in a variable. It can be nice to have the usage info at the top in the comments. If you do that, then grepping the script to print out the info from the comments makes the code DRY.

Comment: @Jens there's hardly any need to call cd before calling usage/help, also the alternative you propose is just bad. I agree with toxalot, it's nice to just cat the program text and see in plain text a summary of what it does.

Answer (score 11):

Any code that is going to be released in the wild should have the following short header:

```
# Script to turn lead into gold
# Copyright (C) 2009 Ima Hacker (i.m.hacker@foo.org)
# Permission to copy and modify is granted under the foo license
# Last revised 1/1/2009
```

Keeping a change log going in code headers is a throwback from when version control systems were terribly inconvenient. A last modified date shows someone how old the script is.

If you are going to be relying on bashisms, use #!/bin/bash , not /bin/sh, as sh is the POSIX invocation of any shell. Even if /bin/sh points to bash, many features will be turned off if you run it via /bin/sh. Most Linux distributions will not take scripts that rely on bashisms, try to be portable.

When it comes to inheriting other people's scripts, I've found that folks tend to comment heavily where it's not needed (e.g. `# loop over $var`) and very sporadically where comments *are* needed (e.g. a super-long Perl one-liner or JVM execution with dozens of arguments). This is not unique to shell scripting at all, it's a problem in many established code bases, but it's especially frustrating in scripts. I don't know what `/bin/foo -- {mile long list of arguments}` does by looking at it, but I do know the constructs of writing a script. Comments are also very much appreciated where you're doing something that looks a little nuts on the surface.

Some shells don't like to be fed typed 'local' variables. I believe to this day Busybox (a common rescue shell) is one of them. Make GLOBALS_OBVIOUS instead, it's much easier to read, especially when debugging via /bin/sh -x ./script.sh.

My personal preference is to let logic speak for itself and minimize work for the parser. For instance, many people might write:

```
if [ $i = 1 ]; then
    ... some code 
fi
```

Where I'd just:

```
[ $i = 1 ] && {
    ... some code
}
```

Likewise, someone might write:

```
if [ $i -ne 1 ]; then
   ... some code
fi
```

... where I'd:

```
[ $i = 1 ] || {
   ... some code 
}
```

The only time I use conventional if / then / else is if there's an else-if to throw in the mix.

A horribly insane example of very good portable shell code can be studied by just viewing the 'configure' script in most free software packages that use autoconf. I say insane because its 6300 lines of code that caters to every system known to humankind that has a UNIX like shell. You don't want that kind of bloat, but it is interesting to study some of the various portability hacks within.. such as being nice to those who might point /bin/sh to zsh :)

The only other advice I can give is watch your expansion in here-docs, i.e.

```
cat << EOF > foo.sh
   printf "%s was here" "$name"
EOF
```

... is going to expand $name, when you probably want to leave the variable in place. Solve this via:

```
  printf "%s was here" "\$name"
```

which will leave $name as a variable, instead of expanding it.

I also highly recommend learning how to use trap to catch signals .. and make use of those handlers as boilerplate code. Telling a running script to slow down with a simple SIGUSR1 is quite handy :)

Most new programs that I write (which are tool / command line oriented) start out as shell scripts, it's a great way to prototype UNIX tools.

You might also like the SHC shell script compiler, [check it out here](http://www.datsi.fi.upm.es/%7Efrosal/).

Comment: If you don't want here docs expanded, use << 'EOF' to suppress expansion.  Only use backslashes when you want some things expanded and some things not expanded.

Comment: There are a million reasons why someone would want to add comments to a shell script. It is terrible advice to say it's silly to comment them.

Comment: @DanGrahn Wow, 2009 me wasn't always great at explaining what I wanted to say :) I didn't want to tell folks that all comments were silly, but rather the absence of them on things one can't easily figure out by reading the code in the midst of so many other things (e.g. "loop here") being commented. Edited, any better?

Comment: @TimPost Much better! Sorry for the deadpost, I didn't realize it was so old. TBH, I can count on one hand the number of times I've looked at code and said "too many comments."

Comment: @DanGrahn I don't think there's such a thing as a _bad_ code comment (unless of course it's misleading), but an abundance of comments around the very obvious and a conspicuous lack of comments around what's not very obvious was a maddening theme when DevOps was basically becoming a thing. That's where my brain was when I wrote it. I enjoy opportunities that take me back to old answers like this one :)

Answer (score 10):

This is the header I use for my script shell (bash or ksh).
It is a `man` look alike and it is used to display usage() as well.

```
#!/bin/ksh
#================================================================
# HEADER
#================================================================
#% SYNOPSIS
#+    ${SCRIPT_NAME} [-hv] [-o[file]] args ...
#%
#% DESCRIPTION
#%    This is a script template
#%    to start any good shell script.
#%
#% OPTIONS
#%    -o [file], --output=[file]    Set log file (default=/dev/null)
#%                                  use DEFAULT keyword to autoname file
#%                                  The default value is /dev/null.
#%    -t, --timelog                 Add timestamp to log ("+%y/%m/%d@%H:%M:%S")
#%    -x, --ignorelock              Ignore if lock file exists
#%    -h, --help                    Print this help
#%    -v, --version                 Print script information
#%
#% EXAMPLES
#%    ${SCRIPT_NAME} -o DEFAULT arg1 arg2
#%
#================================================================
#- IMPLEMENTATION
#-    version         ${SCRIPT_NAME} (www.uxora.com) 0.0.4
#-    author          Michel VONGVILAY
#-    copyright       Copyright (c) http://www.uxora.com
#-    license         GNU General Public License
#-    script_id       12345
#-
#================================================================
#  HISTORY
#     2015/03/01 : mvongvilay : Script creation
#     2015/04/01 : mvongvilay : Add long options and improvements
# 
#================================================================
#  DEBUG OPTION
#    set -n  # Uncomment to check your syntax, without execution.
#    set -x  # Uncomment to debug this shell script
#
#================================================================
# END_OF_HEADER
#================================================================
```

And here is the usage functions to go with:

```
  #== needed variables ==#
SCRIPT_HEADSIZE=$(head -200 ${0} |grep -n "^# END_OF_HEADER" | cut -f1 -d:)
SCRIPT_NAME="$(basename ${0})"

  #== usage functions ==#
usage() { printf "Usage: "; head -${SCRIPT_HEADSIZE:-99} ${0} | grep -e "^#+" | sed -e "s/^#+[ ]*//g" -e "s/\${SCRIPT_NAME}/${SCRIPT_NAME}/g" ; }
usagefull() { head -${SCRIPT_HEADSIZE:-99} ${0} | grep -e "^#[%+-]" | sed -e "s/^#[%+-]//g" -e "s/\${SCRIPT_NAME}/${SCRIPT_NAME}/g" ; }
scriptinfo() { head -${SCRIPT_HEADSIZE:-99} ${0} | grep -e "^#-" | sed -e "s/^#-//g" -e "s/\${SCRIPT_NAME}/${SCRIPT_NAME}/g"; }
```

Here is what you should obtain:

```
# Display help
$ ./template.sh --help

    SYNOPSIS
    template.sh [-hv] [-o[file]] args ...

    DESCRIPTION
    This is a script template
    to start any good shell script.

    OPTIONS
    -o [file], --output=[file]    Set log file (default=/dev/null)
    use DEFAULT keyword to autoname file
    The default value is /dev/null.
    -t, --timelog                 Add timestamp to log ("+%y/%m/%d@%H:%M:%S")
    -x, --ignorelock              Ignore if lock file exists
    -h, --help                    Print this help
    -v, --version                 Print script information

    EXAMPLES
    template.sh -o DEFAULT arg1 arg2

    IMPLEMENTATION
    version         template.sh (www.uxora.com) 0.0.4
    author          Michel VONGVILAY
    copyright       Copyright (c) http://www.uxora.com
    license         GNU General Public License
    script_id       12345

# Display version info
$ ./template.sh -v

    IMPLEMENTATION
    version         template.sh (www.uxora.com) 0.0.4
    author          Michel VONGVILAY
    copyright       Copyright (c) http://www.uxora.com
    license         GNU General Public License
    script_id       12345
```

You can get the full script template here: http://www.uxora.com/unix/shell-script/18-shell-script-template

Comment: Your post doesn't include your entire template and your site puts the code behind a "social like wall", this should be considered bad behaviour.

Comment: @Hultner here is [a backup](https://pastebin.com/UeBD0kkZ). I added the attribution(s) at the very end of the script.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Your link isn't working either. 
"Error, this is a private paste or is pending moderation. If this paste belongs to you, please login to Pastebin to view it."
It would be better if you'd post it as an answer here directly. I'd upvote you.

Answer (score 9):

Enabling error detection makes it much easier to detect problems in the script early:

```
set -o errexit
```

Exit script on first error. That way you avoid continuing on to do something which depended on something earlier in the script, perhaps ending up with some weird system state.

```
set -o nounset
```

Treat references to unset variables as errors. Very important to avoid running things like `rm -you_know_what "$var/"` with an unset `$var`. If you know that the variable can be unset, and this is a safe situation, you can use `${var-value}` to use a different value if it's unset or `${var:-value}` to use a different value if it's unset *or* empty.

```
set -o noclobber
```

It's easy to make the mistake of inserting a `>` where you meant to insert `<`, and overwrite some file which you meant to read. If you need to clobber a file in your script, you can disable this before the relevant line and enable it again afterwards.

```
set -o pipefail
```

Use the first non-zero exit code (if any) of a set of piped command as the exit code of the full set of commands. This makes it easier to debug piped commands.

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

Avoid that your `/foo/*` glob is interpreted *literally* if there are no files matching that expression.

You can combine all of these in two lines:

```
set -o errexit -o nounset -o noclobber -o pipefail
shopt -s nullglob
```

Answer (score 5):

My bash template is as below(set in my [vim configuration](https://github.com/hzheng/vimconf/blob/master/templates/sh)):

```
#!/bin/bash

## DESCRIPTION: 

## AUTHOR: $USER_FULLNAME

declare -r SCRIPT_NAME=$(basename "$BASH_SOURCE" .sh)

## exit the shell(default status code: 1) after printing the message to stderr
bail() {
    echo -ne "$1" >&2
    exit ${2-1}
} 

## help message
declare -r HELP_MSG="Usage: $SCRIPT_NAME [OPTION]... [ARG]...
  -h    display this help and exit
"

## print the usage and exit the shell(default status code: 2)
usage() {
    declare status=2
    if [[ "$1" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
        status=$1
        shift
    fi
    bail "${1}$HELP_MSG" $status
}

while getopts ":h" opt; do
    case $opt in
        h)
            usage 0
            ;;
        \?)
            usage "Invalid option: -$OPTARG \n"
            ;;
    esac
done

shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
[[ "$#" -lt 1 ]] && usage "Too few arguments\n"

#==========MAIN CODE BELOW==========
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest

```
#!/bin/ksh
```

and that's it.  Heavyweight block comments for shell scripts?  I get the willies.

Suggestions:

1. Documentation should be data or code, not comments.  At least a `usage()` function.  Have a look at how ksh and the other AST tools document themselves with --man options on every command.  (Can't link because the web site is down.)
2. Declare local variables with `typeset`.  That's what it's for.  No need for nasty underscores.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, I have a few conventions I like to stick to for every script I write.
I write all scripts with assumption that other people might read them.

I start every script with my header,

```
#!/bin/bash
# [ID LINE]
##
## FILE: [Filename]
##
## DESCRIPTION: [Description]
##
## AUTHOR: [Author]
##
## DATE: [XX_XX_XXXX.XX_XX_XX]
## 
## VERSION: [Version]
##
## USAGE: [Usage]
##
```

I use that date format, for easier grep/searching.
I use the '[' braces to indicate text people need to enter themselves.
if they occur outside a comment, I try to start them with '#['.
That way if someone pastes them as is, it wont be mistaken for input or a test command.  Check the usage section on a man page, to see this style as an example.

When I want to comment out a line of code, I use a single '#'.  When I am doing a comment as a note, I use a double '##'.  The  `/etc/nanorc` uses that convention also. I find it helpful, to differentiate a comment that was chosen not to execute; verses a comment that was created as a note.

All my shell variables, I prefer to do in CAPS.  I try to keep between 4 - 8 characters, unless otherwise necessary. The names relate, as best as possible, with their usage.

I also always exit with 0 if successful, or a 1 for errors.  If the script has many different types of errors (and would actually help someone, or could be used in some code in some way), I would choose a documented sequence over 1.
In general, exit codes are not as strictly enforced in the *nix world.  Unfortunately I have never found a good general number scheme.

I like to process arguments in the standard manner.  I always prefer getopts, to getopt.  I never do some hack with 'read' commands and if statements.  I also like to use the case statement, to avoid nested ifs.  I use a translating script for long options, so --help means -h to getopts.  I write all scripts in either bash (if acceptable) or generic sh.

I NEVER use bash interpreted symbols (or any interpreted symbol) in filenames, or any name for that matter.
specifically... " ' ` $ & * # () {} [] -, I use _ for spaces.

Remember, these are just conventions.  Best practice, of coarse, but sometimes you are forced outside the lines.  The most important is to be consistent across and within your projects.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is to make a script that creates a header for a script & and have it auto open in your favorite editor. I saw a guy do that at this site:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577862-bash-script-to-create-a-header-for-bash-scripts/?in=lang-bash

```
#!/bin/bash -       
#title           :mkscript.sh
#description     :This script will make a header for a bash script.
#author          :your_name_here
#date            :20110831
#version         :0.3    
#usage           :bash mkscript.sh
#notes           :Vim and Emacs are needed to use this script.
#bash_version    :4.1.5(1)-release
#===============================================================================
```