# Use getopts like getopt on shell

Tags: bash, shell, getopt, getopts

system:  freebsd 9.2

I want to use getopts to parse command line. Such as

```
./tesh.sh -o good a.c  
can get  good.out

./tesh.sh -o a.c   
can get a.out
```

But in getopts there is no "option" variable. 
Does anyone know how to solve this problem? 
I found lots of webpages but no one can solve it.

here is my code

```
#!/bin/bash


while getopts "hs:o:" optname
do
    case "$optname" in
    "h")
        echo "Option $optname is specified"
        ;;
    "s")
        echo "Option $optname has value $OPTARG"
        ;;
    "o")    
        echo "$optname"
        ;;
    "?")
        echo "Unknown option $OPTARG"
        ;;
    ":")
    ;;
    *)
        # Should not occur
        echo "Unknown error while processing options"
        ;;
    esac
    echo "OPTIND is now $OPTIND"
done
```

if i type ./test.sh -o a.c
it will print echo "$optname"

and i want that
if i type
./test.sh -o 
can also print echo "$optname"

now it will print wrong message

thx!

Comment: Explain more about your scenario as it is not clear and confusion what your requirement is.

Comment: See [Shell script templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430078/shell-script-templates/430680#430680); one part of the answer has an outline of how to use `getopts` to parse a command line.  You may also find useful information in [Using `getopts` in Bash shell script to get long and short command line options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options/402413#402413) helpful too.

Comment: @SriharshaKalluru thx ! i add more about my question

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thx!  but i can find the solution what i want =(

Comment: If you define "-o" option requiring an argument and you do not provide an argument, you'll get an error message.

Comment: thx 
so i want to know if any way to solve this
such gcc complier
gcc -o great.out a.c  it will generally great.out
and  gcc -o a.c    it will generally a.out

Comment: Are you asking for an optional output file name after the `-o` option? If so, it will be hard to code. The way getopt and getopts work will use the `a.c` name in your `script -o a.c` command line as the argument to `-o`. You would have to analyze the name and decide it isn't the output filename and arrange to (1) insert the correct derived name and (2) process whatever got treated as the option argument correctly.  Messy, at best. There are so many pitfalls on the way that I would not try to do it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  OK!  I will find the other way !   thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your requirement you need not use getopts and you can use the following code to make it happen.

If only -o is given it will be treated as a flag.
If -o is givne with any value then it is treated as option.

```
> cat test
#!/bin/bash

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
case $1 in
        -h) echo "Option $optname is specified" ;;
        -s) VAL_S=$2; echo "Option $optname has value $VAL_S" ;shift;;
        -o) VAL_O=$2; F=$(echo $VAL_O |cut -c1);
            if [ "$F" = "-" -o -z "$F" ]; then
                echo "-o is a flag"
                DEFAULT=a.c
            else
                echo "-o is a option"
                DEFAULT=$VAL_O
                shift
            fi
        ;;
        *) echo "Unknown option $OPTARG" ;exit ;;
esac
shift
done
```

I ran it in the possible cases.

```
> ./test -o
-o is a flag
> ./test -o a.c
-o is a option
> ./test -o -h
-o is a flag
Option  is specified
> ./test -o a.c -h
-o is a option
Option  is specified
```