# How to run linux shell script with full named boolean flags?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Need to run shell script with parameters to perform some routine.
And I want to this script runs with boolean flags wit full names like

`./deploy.sh --auto-maintenance --migration`

That's for those who run this script it will be readable and they saw what they do.

Need something like in this reply
[Boolean cli flag using getopts in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31974550/boolean-cli-flag-using-getopts-in-bash)
but here author used short options like `./script.sh -x -a` etc. Works fine, but it doesn't match to my task.

I'm facing this first time and enerally problem is that I don't know how to read such full named options.

Thanks for any example.

Comment: Does `man 1 getopt` not answer your question?

Comment: Not sure. Googling this I can't see any convenient info. Would you be more specific?

Comment: Why bother with `getopts` at all? Just examine the arguments and compare them to strings, perhaps using a case statement.  And why bother with the hyphens?  It's easier to type `./deploy auto-maintenance migration`.  There's no need to pretend they are flags.